# Iterating through two columns of a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, telegram

I'm making a bot in PHP for telegram API and I'm using MySQL.
I have a table for every user that stores id, name, etc.
I wrote a piece of code to send number of users and select the id of every user to make a link with it, using a loop.
I was wondering how I can iterate through the names at the same time
do I need another loop or I should use MySQL code?

```
$alltotal = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect,"select id from user"));
$ids=array();
$idarray =mysqli_query($connect,"select id from user"); 
        api('sendmessage',[
        'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
        'text'=>"total users : $alltotal: ",
        ]);
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($idarray)){
    $ids[]=$row['id'];
        api('sendmessage',[
        'parse_mode'=>'MarkdownV2',
        'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
        'text'=>"(tg://user?id=".$row[0].")",
]);
}
```

Comment: `SELECT id, name FROM user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select multiple columns in a single query.

Also, don't execute the query multiple times. You can use `mysqli_num_rows($idarray)` to get the number of rows.

```
$idarray = mysqli_query($connect,"select id, name from user");
$alltotal = mysqli_num_rows($idarray);
api('sendmessage',[
    'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
    'text'=>"total users : $alltotal: ",
]);
$ids_and_names = [];
while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($idarray)){
    $ids_and_names[] = $row;
    api('sendmessage',[
        'parse_mode'=>'MarkdownV2',
        'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
        'text'=>"(tg://user?id=".$row['id'].")",
    ]);
}
```